# Need - Google Endpoint StackDriver IPs sending Webhook Alerts

Tags: alert, endpoint, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I need the list of End Point IPs or IP Ranges sending alert from Stackdriver Webhook Channel. This is required so that I can whitelist those IPs at my NetCool server to receive them. Otherwise the alerts sending by Stackdriver through Webhook channel to my NetCool Webhook Server are getting rejected by firewall.I tried to trace the IPs but they are coming like - 66.102.6.63,
66.249.93.35, 66.102.8.227 ... other than 66 nothing is common. So it looks to me the IPs may be masked. Please help me. The list should be similar :

Azure : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/action-groups?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring

similar informations are also available at AWS and. AliBaba

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver intentionally does not publish the IP ranges of webhooks, because it is a dynamic pool.

From a security standpoint, doing a reverse DNS lookup of the caller IP address and verifying that it ends in ".google.com" is probably a better approach.

Another possibility is to rely on the integration with Cloud Pub/Sub [1] instead of Webhook.

The Cloud Pub/Sub integration provides an alternative programmatic approach to handling alerts that supports more sophisticated auth such as JWT-based auth, which we would recommend for auth over IP-based whitelisting.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push